# Are floating-point numbers normalised by computers or humans?

Tags: floating-point

I keep seeing posts and articles about how to normalise a floating-point number, why that's done and how such a number is represented in binary. But no one seems to mention who/what the normalisation process is done by in the first place. Forgive me if it sounds like a really dumb question, I'm just a beginner, but are normalised forms of these numbers generated by a computer itself, or hard-coded into it by humans?

Comment: When you are converting an integer to a float in a programming language your CPU does normalization. e.g. $32$ is converted to $2^5*1.0$. I think you should read about how computers handle flloats. [here is a good place to start](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format). Basically your computer uses normalization to save space when storing floating point numbers. IEEE 754 32-bit floats are a format that allows that.

Comment: Normal form is a convention that allows to have a unique representation for all the numbers that are representable in a floating point format.  Normalizing a floating point number is done by whoever wants to do it or is told to do it. For example, in a floating point with base $b=10$, exponent from $-3$ to $3$ and significand with $3$ digits, you can represent $123$ only as $1.23\times 10^2$. There is no other representable number equal to it. However, the number $120$ can be represented as $1.20\times 10^2$ or as $0.12\times 10^{3}$.

Comment: You could just as well ask who converts decimals to binary, humans or computers.